# Getting a NSDictionary that has a particular key inside an array

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have an NSArray of NSDictionaries.

The dictionaries has keys like this: color, number, code, description and size.

Now I have a key and I want to locate that dictionary inside the array, some magic command like:

```
NSDictionary *oneDict = [get a dictionary from myArray where "code" is equal to "32"];
```

code is a key, 32 a value.

I know how to enumerate the array and search one by one every dict, but I know objective-c is a bag full of "tricks" and a "magic command" may exist to extract surgically this dictionary from the array in one line.

Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with an NSPredicate simpler:

```
NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"code MATCHES[cd] %@", value];
NSArray *result = [myArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

The result array will hold all NSDictionaries that did match the value.
Take a look at the NSPredicate [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html)
It is very powerful

Answer (score 2):

You can use indexOfObjectPassingTest to get the object index:

```
NSUInteger index = [myArray indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSDictionary* dict = obj;
    return [obj[@"code"] intValue] == 32;
}];
```

If not found, result will be NSNotFound;

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to do the lookup many times and don't mind spending some time on setup, you could create a dictionary that maps the values of `code` to the dictionaries that contain those values. i.e.:

```
NSDictionary * mapping = [ NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:myArray forKeys:[ myArray valueForKey:@"code" ] ]
id answer = mapping[@"32" ] ;
```

This only works if `code` contains unique values. If the values are not unique:

```
NSArray * codeValues = [ myArray valueForKey:@"code" ] ;
NSIndexSet indexes = [ codeValues indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id object){ [ object isEqual:@"32" ] } ] ;
NSArray * matchingDictionaries = [ myArray objectsAtIndexes:indexes ] ;
```

`matchingDictionaries` will be an array containing dictionaries where `code` is `@"32"`.

Replace `@"32"` in these examples with the value of `code` you wish to find, &c.